# Unwanted stacked data in date_plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, stacked

I'm trying to display to curves. The abscesses are dates and the ordinates are double value (in this case power).
The data are not provided with the same dates. But when two dates matches, the second set of data added is stacked on the previous one.

**Example 1:** FR is added after DE and has 4 times less data
[image: Example 1: FR is added after DE and has 4 times less data]

**Example 2:** DE is added after FR and has 4 times more data.
[image: Example 2: DE is added after FR and has 4 times more data.]

The code i'm currently running is :

```py
    # Clean figure
    fig = plt.figure()

    for country in ['DE', 'FR']:

        production = getProduction(
            country=country,
            start=start,
            end=end,
            session=session,
            verbose=False,
            debug=False)

        allTimeseries = production['all']['timeseries']

        print(allTimeseries)

        timestamps = []
        values = []
        for date in allTimeseries.keys():
            timestamps.append(date)
            values.append(allTimeseries[date]['power']['quantity'])

        # Add the plot to the figure
        plt.plot_date(timestamps, values, label=country, antialiased=True)

    plt.xticks(rotation=30, ha="right")
    plt.legend(loc='upper left', ncol=1)

    # plt.show()
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig('test.png', dpi=fig.dpi)
```

How to prevent the two series to stack ?

Comment: How should it look like instead?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).